# Laravel relationships - whereHas on hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

1 entry in my `delivery` table is related to:

- stock_movements
- delivery_items

Delivery has:

```
public function deliveryItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DeliveryItem::class);
}

public function stockMovements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockMovement::class,'entity_id');
}
```

DeliveryItem has:

```
public function stockMovements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockMovement::class, 'product_id', 'product_id')
        ->where('entity_id', $this->delivery_id);
}
```

The deliveryItems table contains a list of items that are due on the delivery and the stockMovements table contains what is due and what has been received. There is a situation where I may have a line in my deliveryItems table but no correlating line in the stockMovements. I am trying to get a collection of these items.

I have tried things like:

```
$delivery->deliveryItems()->whereHas('stockMovements')->get() //returns empty collection. Can use whereNotHas to get the opposite if it worked.
```

^^ This above returns an empty collection.

```
foreach($delivery->deliveryItems as $item){
    dump($item->whereHas('stockMovements')->get());
}
```

^^ This seems to produce the correct result but produces the same result for each of the loops. I don't believe I need the foreach but am unsure hot to get it working without it! I think I need to run the whereHas directly on the deliveryItems collection but am unable to work out how to.

Comment: you can try `doesntHave`

Comment: I have got whereDoesntHave working also.... but can I do this outside of the foreach loop? I want something like `$delivery->deliveryItems->whereDoesntHave('stockMovements')->get()` but that does not work as deliveryItems is a collection already...

Comment: `whereDoesntHave` need when we need extra filter, if not then just use `doesntHave`

Comment: try `$delivery->deliveryItems()->doesntHave('stockMovements')->get()`

Comment: That works also. I have been using it with and without the extra filters. I cannot get it to work without the foreach though. When I run in the foreach, each iteration of the loop it generates the same (and correct) result. If I run it like `$delivery->deliveryItems()->has('stockMovements')->get()` on the query builder, I get a result but its the wrong one!

Comment: if I run the has/doesntHave on the deliveryItems() query builder then it does not seem to produce the correct result. When I change the amount of entries in my stockMovement table the results stay the same. doesntHave seems to provide me with the entire collection of the items table. has prodvides me with nothing.

Comment: i have updated answer, please try that once

Answer (score 2):

can you try this

```
$delivery = Delivery::with(['deliveryItems' => function($query){
                  $query->doesntHave('stockMovements');
              }])->find($deliveryId);

dd($delivery->deliveryItems);
```

Comment: These do not work. `doesnthave` returns all results while `has` returns none... however I think my issue is that my stockMovement is not working when accessed these ways. If I print out `$this->product_id` from inside the stockMovements() relationship it shows null... I am stuck as to why this is though. Using this relationship from an item works fine, just not from a collection.

Comment: what about adding `delivery_id` at time of fetching

Comment: I could do yes... any idea why it would not be working through. Is it because the relationship back to the delivery is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

You may try by removing `where('entity_id', $this->delivery_id)` condition in relationship method of `DeliveryItem` model.

```
public function stockMovements()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockMovement::class, 'product_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Comment: I have found out that `$this->delivery_id` is returning null in this relationship when used this way. When I access it from a single item it works fine but not from the query builder. i.e. `foreach () $item->stockMovemements` works fine but `$delivery->deliveryItems()->doesntHave('stockMovements')` results in a null product_id

Comment: Removing the `where('entity_id', $this->delivery_id)` allows it to work... however if I need this for my other relationships what can I do? Is the reason the $this->delivery_id is not coming through due to a relationship back from the stockMovements to the Delivery?

Comment: Do you have a bit of an explanation as to how this works? If I remove the `where('entity_id', $this->delivery_id)` how does eloquent know that it should ignore other lines which have the same `product_id` but a different `entity_id`?

Comment: You may apply your condition in  `Closure` callback e.i. `where`, `whereHas`, `with`.